# Select those that HAVE NEVER had certain entry

Tags: mysql

I have a table of services that have been provided to clients.  I'm trying to make a query that selects all the clients who received a service that WEREN'T provided by a certain user.

So consider this table...

```
id_client | id_service | id_user
--------------------------------
    5     |     3      |    2
    7     |     4      |    2
    7     |     4      |    1
    9     |     4      |    2
    8     |     4      |    1
```

If I write the query like this:

```
SELECT id_client FROM table WHERE id_service=4 AND id_user<>1
```

I still end up getting id_client 7.  But I don't want to get client 7 because that client HAS received that service from user 1. (They're showing up because they've also received that service from user 2)

In the example above I would only want to be returned with client 9

How can I write the query to make sure that clients that have EVER received service 4 from user 1 don't show up?

Comment: `id_client` never has a value of `1` in your table, so how can you be getting a record with `id_client` equal to `1`?

Comment: Sorry.  Meant to put id_client 7.  Just updated it...

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_client
FROM yourtable t
WHERE id_service = 4 AND id_client NOT IN
 (SELECT DISTINCT id_client
 FROM yourtable t
 WHERE id_user = 1
 )
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd write it like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_client
FROM mytable t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable t2
  ON t1.id_client = t2.id_client AND t2.id_user = 1
WHERE t2.id_client IS NULL
```

When the conditions of a left outer join are not met, the row on the left side is still returned, and all the columns for the row on the right side are null.  So if you search for cases of null in a column that would be certain to be non-null if there were a match, you know the outer join found no match.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id_client
FROM   table
WHERE  id_service = 4
GROUP  BY id_client
HAVING MAX(CASE
             WHEN id_user = 1 THEN 2
                              ELSE 1
            END) = 1
```

Comment: Hey Martin, your solution and Saket's both do the trick.  But yours is really intriguing.  I didn't know you could use CASEs like that in SQL.  Can I ask what the benefits are, though, of doing it this way as opposed to Saket's?

Comment: @Steven- It will depend on your data and indexes which one will work out best for you in practice. Try them both out.